# Conversion of bit pattern to float value in Swift

Tags: swift, type-conversion, fourcc

I am stuck at the conversion of specified bit patterns to the final value.
I have the following FourCC:

SP78
SP3C
SP69
SP4B
SP5A

The S stands for a signed floating point. The first digit is the integer bit count while the second one stands for the fraction bit count (Although it is a FourCC, only 2 bytes are used).

So the types are:

```
SP78 // floating point signed, 1 sign bit, 7 bits integer, 8 fraction bits
SP3C // floating point signed, 1 sign bit, 3 bits integer, 12 fraction bits
SP69 // floating point signed, 1 sign bit, 6 bits integer, 9 fraction bits
SP4B // floating point signed, 1 sign bit, 4 bits integer, 11 fraction bits
SP5A // floating point signed, 1 sign bit, 5 bits integer, 10 fraction bits
```

How do I convert these bit patterns into a Double in Swift?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Take it as a signed 16bit value, cast to float and divide by 2^fractionbits. And FourCC relates to the SP78 etc, not the data

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much!